# How to Alias a column header in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that I have imported from an external file.  The column names aren't always the same depending on who created the file that I imported.  I have a list of the possible names and I want to grab the column based on the list. The order of the columns isn't always the same.

```
print(df_1)

     GR      RHOB
0    300     10
1    400     11

print(df_2)

     RHOB   GAMMA
0    14      500
1    15      600
```

in the above example, GR and GAMMA are the same and I need to be able to call either one by something like:

```
print(df_1.GAMMA_ALIAS)

     GR      
0    300     
1    400  

print(df_2.GAMMA_ALIAS)

     GAMMA
0    500
1    600
```

I have a list of all of the possible names for the Gamma column.

Comment: Why not do it the other way around? Standardize the names in your dataframes so that you can call it by the same name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alias for column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46096307/alias-for-column-in-pandas)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46096307). Short answer: column aliasing [is not supported yet](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11723).

Comment: Write a python function to take the dataframe as input check its type and add an alias to update the column name by reading new header name.

The question is otherwise too generic for an answer to be given.